# Spring custom annotation: how to inherit attributes?

Tags: java, annotations, spring-annotations

I am creating my own custom shortcut annotation, as described in [Spring Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html#tx-custom-attributes):

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional(value = "Custom", readOnly = true)
public @interface CustomTransactional {
}
```

Is it possible, that with my custom annotation I could be also able to set any other attributes, which are available in `@Transactional`? I would like to able use my annotation, for example, like this:

```
@CustomTransactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class MyClass {

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that will not work, if you want additional attributes that will have to be set on your custom annotation itself this way:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional(value = "Custom", readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public @interface CustomTransactional {
}
```

A solution (bad one :-) ) could be to define multiple annotations with the base set of cases that you see for your scenario:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional(value = "Custom", readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public @interface CustomTransactionalWithRequired {
}

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional(value = "Custom", readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTED)
public @interface CustomTransactionalWithSupported {
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of such scenario, but then I would end up with MANY annotation - for each sensible attribute combination ;)

Comment: Yes, I thought so, that is the reason why I put it as a bad solution :-) . don't see any other option than using `@Transactional` itself if that is the case, custom stereotype annotations will help if you have a fixed set of attributes for your annotations.

Answer (score 2):

In (at least) Spring 4, you can do this by specifying the element inside the annotation, e.g.:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional(value = "Custom", readOnly = true)
public @interface CustomTransactional {
    Propagation propagation() default Propagation.SUPPORTED;
}
```

Source: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-meta-annotations

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring Framework 4.2, [@AliasFor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.0.RC3_to_4.2.0.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%204.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/core/annotation/AliasFor.html) annotation can be used to declare aliases for annotation attributes.

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional
public @interface CustomTransactional {
  @AliasFor(annotation = Transactional.class, attribute = "propagation")
  Propagation propagation() default Propagation.REQUIRED;
}
```